# OAuth 2.0 access token isn't refreshed, gives 401 Error : Token Invalid when used

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401

I am currently using the Youtube API for a desktop application in C++. I am trying to implement the direct upload, which requires an authentication. I naturally choose OAuth 2.0, I followed the [Google example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow) and apparently everything worked well, I've got an access token and a refresh token, without any error returned.

However, when I try to use the access token to upload a video (I put it in the `Authorization : Bearer` header), I get an error `401 : Unauthorized` with the description `Token Invalid`.

I then tried to refresh the access token right before requesting the upload (which means I try to refresh right after retrieving the access token, since the two operations are consecutive in my application's flow). The access token remained unchanged : **I received the same access token from the refresh request and the exchange request**.

I first thought it meant an access token should be refreshed only when it expires, but it is apparently not true : using the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), it seems clear that refreshing a not yet expired token works fine and gives a different access token.

Any idea on what the problem could be ? Is the 401 error linked to the fact that I am not able to refresh the token ?

Edit : Here are the request and the response as shown in Fiddler

Request :

```
POST http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: xx
Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=MY_DEV_KEY
Slug: test.avi
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="f93dcbA3"
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: SOME_STUFF
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Content-Length: 23686
Connection: Keep-Alive

--f93dcbA3
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"><media:group><media:title type="plain">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title><media:description type="plain">I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.</media:description><media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People</media:category><media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords></media:group></entry>
--f93dcbA3
Content-Type: video/avi
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<My file binary data>
--f93dcbA3--
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-GData-User-Country: FR
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",service="youtube"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 13
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UrVDA94Fk5VFn1ng-2q9VFOo2KifLvIEHFOxQ4m66IUSC8sRf3mo5S8UH94mLyupbfANeLQvxMPhPLo6L0wlcaguQW9CQ
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 09:51:23 GMT
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 8 2013 15:32:26 (1373322746)

Token invalid
```

Edit 2 : Request and response using Youtube API v3

Request :

```
POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?part="snippet" HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
X-gdata-key: DEV_KEY
Content-length: 42190
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="===============1679429526=="
Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN

--===============1679429526==
Content-type: application/json

{
    "snippet": 
    {
        "title": "test"
    }
}

--===============1679429526==
Content-type: video/avi

<BINARY DATA - 41984B>
--===============1679429526==--
```

Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 229
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 8 2013 15:32:26 (1373322746)
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 22:14:03 GMT
Content-type: application/json

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badContent",
    "message": "Unsupported content with type: video/avi"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unsupported content with type: video/avi"
 }
}
```

Comment: Access tokens can be refreshed at any time. As a quick check, do you have a Python interpreter on your system? If so a good sanity check is to use the tokens provided by this sample: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python. The tokens will be in a .json file - you can also put your C++ tokens into the .json and see what happens. You'll need to install the google-api-python-client via pip/easy_install.

Comment: Also another note: you can plug in your client ID and client secret into the OAuth playground under the "Gear" icon. This'll help you get a usable access token that you can plug into your C++ code.

Comment: I seems to be impossible to edit the redirect URIs for an Installed Application, which makes the use of my own credentials in the OAuth 2.0 Playground impossible as well. I created a ClientID for a web application, I could get the tokens in the Playground, tried to use it in my app, still the same error. Doing the request from the Playground itself doesn't return a 401 error, but a "400 Bad request : No file found in request" error, although I suppose this is [a different problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664700/no-file-found-in-request-with-youtube-api-in-oauth-2-0-playground).

Comment: I have edited my post to show the request and the reponse.

Comment: Interesting - okay, you're using the v2 API. The OAuth playground demonstrates use of the v3 API instead, which is what is being maintained going forward. This *shouldn't* matter, because auth should work the same, but can you take a look at porting to v3 instead so we can narrow down the list of possibilities? Our support will be geared towards v3 going forward and not v2.

Comment: As far as the OAuth 2.0 playground goes, you *can* use a Web Application flow for an installed app (just for testing purposes), so you could create a new key and give it a shot.

Comment: Ok, i made a second edit showing the error I am getting when testing the v3 direct upload with the Playground. What does "unsupported content" means, I am quite surprised to have that kind of message for a .avi file. Does it mean my request is not well formated ?

Comment: I finally managed to upload a video from my C++ application using the [Resumable Upload flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol). Good thing this part gives HTTP requests examples instead of only using the available Client Libraries, I wish it was the same for the whole doc. However, I am quite surprised that I didn't need to provide my developer key with the request for it to work, contrary to what is said in the Youtube API Partner Dashboard. Is it normal ?